# OpenLayers: Switch layer off when switching another layer on

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

As the title says, I want to turn layers off when turning another layer on.
I wrote a function that works. However, I have to click the layer twice in the LayerSwitcher to turn the layer on that I want to see.

The first click turns the other layers off but only a second click turns the actual layer tho show on. Can somebody tell me where I am wrong in my code?

```
    function getVLayers(showLayer){
        for (var i=0; i < map.layers.length; i += 1){
            if (map.layers[i].visibility){
                if (map.layers[i].name == showLayer && map.layers[i].name == "OpenStreetMap"){

                } else {
                    map.layers[i].setVisibility(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    map.events.register("changelayer", this, function(e){
        getVLayers(e.layer.name);
    });
```

Comment: It may be that you haven't set the isBaseLayer property of each layer to "true". If your layers are base layers, the sort of functionality you are trying to achieve should be built-in.

Comment: I do have the OSM layer as baselayer in there and I might be wrong, but wouldn't all the layers where I set the isBaseLayer property to true turn off the OSM layer as well?